# Difference between == and .equals()?

Tags: java, string

I am learning Java now. When I use `==` and `.equals()` for String comparisons, I am getting different results. But there is no compilation error. Can anyone explain the difference between these two operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` tests for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

Example:

```
String fooString1 = new String("Java");
String fooString2 = new String("Java");

// false
fooString1 == fooString2;

// true
fooString1.equals(fooString2);
```

Note:

`==` handles null strings values.

`.equals()` from a null string will cause `Null Pointer Exception`

Comment: Thanks Gokul. This is much useful.

Answer (score 2):

- `s1 == s2` compares string *references*; this is very rarely what you want.
- `s1.equals(s2)` compares the two *character sequences*; this is almost always what you want.

Answer (score 0):

when == is used for comparision between String then it checks the reference of the objects. But when equals is used it actually checks the contents of the String. So for example

```
  String a = new String("ab");
  String b = new String("ab");
  if(a==b) ///will return false because both objects are stored on the different locations in memory

   if(a.equals(b)) // will return true because it will check the contents of the String
```

i hope this helps